# Need help in specifying Regex for \ in grep

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following string in the GREPTEXT.TXT file:

```
APLLE ME APPLE ASA\LE Ale\A\L
```

i want to search the A\L pattern match in the above string. i have tried escaping \ as

```
grep -E A\\L GREPTEST.TXT
```

but grep returns no result.

How should i match it?

Comment: What if you `grep -E 'A\\L' GREPTEST.TXT`? Note the single quotes.

Comment: yes it works, now the shell does not interprets \. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell interprets backslashes as well. Simply put the argument in quotes:

```
$ echo 'APLLE ME APPLE ASA\LE Ale\A\L' > GREPTEST.TXT
$ grep -E 'A\\L' GREPTEST.TXT
APLLE ME APPLE ASA\LE Ale\A\L
```